# how do I get this promise back to the controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, promise

So I have a series of functions I've defined in the service that upload an image to my Amazon s3 bucket, and I can console.log and alert in the service itself and everything is coming back correct.

However, now I want to return that promise to the controller so I can let the user know the upload is finished. I'm just not sure how I would do that. I've tried putting returns at the filereader.onload but then I get errors saying that what I've given back isn't a promise and such. Here's my code:

```
angular.module("testApp", [])
.controller("testCtrl", function($scope, amazonService) {
    $scope.test = "leeroy jenkins";

    $scope.upload = function() {
        amazonService.uploadImage($('#file'));
    }
})
.service("amazonService", function($http) {
    var url = "/api/"
    var uploadImageFilestream = function(obj) {
        return $http({
            method: "PUT",
            url: url + "media/images",
            data: obj
        }).then(function(res) {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                alert("upload successful!");
            }
            return res;
        });
    }

    var formatFileName = function(filename, newBase) {
        //first, get the file extension
        var extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."));
        return newBase + extension;
    }

    this.uploadImage = function(obj) {
        var file = obj[0].files[0];
        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        fileReader.onload = function(loaded) {
            uploadImageFilestream({fileName: formatFileName(file.name, "test1"), fileBody: loaded.target.result});
        }

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
})
```

I know that if I combined the uploadImageFilestream function with the uploadImage function it would work, but I'm not sure how to structure it with the promise in a separate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$q`:

```
.service("amazonService", function($http, $q) {
    var url = "/api/"
    var uploadImageFilestream = function(obj) {
        return $http({
            method: "PUT",
            url: url + "media/images",
            data: obj
        });
    }

    var formatFileName = function(filename, newBase) {
        //first, get the file extension
        var extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."));
        return newBase + extension;
    }

    this.uploadImage = function(obj) {
        var file = obj[0].files[0];
        var fileReader = new FileReader();

        var deferer = $q.defer();

        fileReader.onload = function(loaded) {
            uploadImageFilestream({fileName: formatFileName(file.name, "test1"), fileBody: loaded.target.result})
            .then(function(res) {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    deferer.resolve();
                    alert("upload successful!");
                }
                return res;
            });
        }

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);

        return deferer.promise;
    }
})
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error that says "amazonservice.uploadImage(...).then is not a function when I try to add the .then to the controller

Comment: Figured it out, had to change the last line to return deferer.promise

Answer (score 0):

You should be using $q service of AngularJs to create deferred object and return promise.
I have modified the following code as to demonstrate way to use promises.

```
angular.module("testApp", [])
.controller("testCtrl", function($scope, amazonService) {
    $scope.test = "leeroy jenkins";

    $scope.upload = function() {
        var promise = amazonService.uploadImage($('#file')); // call to function returns promise 
        promise.then(function(){ // when promise is resolved, desired data is passed
            alert("success");
        }).catch(function(error){ // when promise is rejected, related error object is passed
            alert("failure");
        });
    }
})
.service("amazonService", function($http, $q) { // added $q service to handle promises
    var url = "/api/"
    var uploadImageFilestream = function(obj) {
        return $http({
            method: "PUT",
            url: url + "media/images",
            data: obj
        }).then(function(res) {
            if (res.status === 200) {
                alert("upload successful!");
            }
            return res;
        });
    }

    var formatFileName = function(filename, newBase) {
        //first, get the file extension
        var extension = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("."));
        return newBase + extension;
    }

    this.uploadImage = function(obj) {
        var file = obj[0].files[0];
        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        var deferredObject = $q.defer(); // added deferred object which will be used to return promise and resolve or reject is as shown below
        fileReader.onload = function(loaded) {
            uploadImageFilestream({fileName: formatFileName(file.name, "test1"), fileBody: loaded.target.result}).then(response){
                deferredObject.resolve(response); // when resolve function of deferred object is called success callback in controller will be called with the data you pass here
            }).catch(function(errorObj){
                deferredObject.reject(errorObj); // when reject function of deferred object is called error callback is controller will be called with the error object you pass here
            });
        }

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
        return deferredObject.promise; // return promise object which will be resolve or reject and accordingly success callback and error callback will be called with then and catch respectively
    }
});
```

Link to [AngularJs Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).
There are other different ways too to create and return promise you can see it in reference.

One other way to create and return promise as given in reference is using $q object as function and passing callback directly as shown below:

```
// for the purpose of this example let's assume that variables `$q` and `okToGreet`
// are available in the current lexical scope (they could have been injected or passed in).
// for the purpose of this example let's assume that variables `$q` and `okToGreet`
// are available in the current lexical scope (they could have been injected or passed in).

function asyncGreet(name) {
  // perform some asynchronous operation, resolve or reject the promise when appropriate.
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (okToGreet(name)) {
        resolve('Hello, ' + name + '!');
      } else {
        reject('Greeting ' + name + ' is not allowed.');
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}

var promise = asyncGreet('Robin Hood');
promise.then(function(greeting) {
  alert('Success: ' + greeting);
}, function(reason) {
  alert('Failed: ' + reason);
});
```